# Using Constructors in C# - getting multiple errors following an almost 2 year old course

Tags: c#, class, constructor

I just started learning C#, having previously learned Python. I know how classes and constructors work in Python with **init**(self,...)

I'm following the Giraffe Academy / FreeCodeCamp tutorial on C#, and I am doing the exact same thing as him (I can't see any difference anyway). Still, I get errors when trying to create a constructor for a book Class. This is my code, and I get like 5 different errors from it:

```
 namespace StuffThingy
    {
        class Book
        {
            public string title;
            public string author;
            public int pages;
        }
        public Book(string aTitle,string aAuthor, int aPages)
        {
            title = aTitle;
            author = aAuthor;
            pages = aPages;
        }
```

It's like it doesn't recognize that I have just defined the public variables before using them in my constructor

Comment: Your constructor is _outside_ the class. You should put it _inside_ the class. Does that fix the issue?

Comment: If an answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put the Constructor INSIDE the class.

```
namespace StuffThingy
{
    class Book
    {
        public string title;
        public string author;
        public int pages;

        public Book(string aTitle,string aAuthor, int aPages)
        {
            title = aTitle;
            author = aAuthor;
            pages = aPages;
        }
    }
}
```